# Dataset is not found when saving a query

Tags: google-bigquery

I just got back to using Google Big Query and a lot has changed from 6 months ago. I was about to work on my normal process of running a query where I save the query in a table in a specific dataset, but it cant find the dataset.

Replicate problem:

- step 1: Click "Compose New Query"
- step 2: Click on "More"
- step 3:
  Select "Query Settings"
- step 4: On the Query Settings menu, select
  "Set a destination table for query results"

after those steps it cant find my dataset.:

[image]

but it's obviously in my project:

[image]

Am I missing something?

Comment: hv u checked ur access again?

Comment: @Mr.Batra I'm the sole owner and Admin. Do I still need to check my access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that you can just force type the Id in this format: **ProjectId.DatasetId** even if it doesn't show in the search results.